# Google Chrome Extension: How to get all urls of opening tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using [chome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query) to get all detail from all tabs are opening in Chrome.

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
  tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
    console.log(tab);
  });
});
```

However, in the results I received, I could not find the URL of the tab page. The information is the same as

```
{
  active: false
  audible: false
  autoDiscardable: true
  discarded: false
  groupId: -1
  height: 748
  highlighted: false
  id: 134
  incognito: false
  index: 1
  mutedInfo: {muted: false}
  pinned: false
  selected: false
  status: "complete"
  width: 1440
  windowId: 4
}
```

Is there a way that allows me to get all the information of the open tabs according to its URL?

My Chrome version: 89.04

Answer (score 0):

Have you add "tabs" permission in manifest.json ?

From https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab

> URL property is only present if the extension's manifest includes the
> "tabs" permission and may be an empty string if the tab has not yet
> committed.

You can use several methods of tabs API without "tabs" permission
but if you want to retreive this kind of information from a query you have to include tabs permission in manifest.

Comment: Thank you I added tabs permission to the manifest file earlier. However, I did not get any information yesterday. After your answer, I got it. Maybe I need to restart my extensions when I do an update.